# Neo4j get_or_create unique REST batch API issue

Tags: rest, batch-file, unique, neo4j

The following REST API batch fails:

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch [{"method":"POST","to":"index/node/name uniqueness=get_or_create","body":{"key":"name","value":"Person1","properties":{"Type":"PERSON"}},"id":1},
{"method":"POST","to":"index/node/name?uniqueness=get_or_create","body":{"key":"name","value":"Person2","properties":{"Type":"PERSON"}},"id":2},
{"method":"POST","to":"{1}/relationships","body":{"type":"Knows","to":"{2}","data":{"Since":"2012"}},"id":3}]
```

with a 500 Internal Server Error.

For some reason it does not seem to be possible to refer to the nodes in the batch with {1} and {2} when using uniqueness=get_or_create. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That might be due to the fact that the index operation doesn't set the location header. Please raise an issue on github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/84 is already pointing out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cypher in the third operation with an index lookup to access the newly created node.

```
start n1=node:name(name={name1}), n2=node:name(name={name2}) 
create n1-[:Knows {props}]->n2
```

with the parameters

```
{
"query":"start n1=node:name(name={name1}), n2=node:name(name={name2}) create n1-[:Knows {props}]->n2",
"params":{"name1":"Person1","name2":"Person2","props":{"Since":"2012"}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the workaround. It will do the trick for now although it would be really nice to see the issue fixed since my relationship objects are harder to serialize to a cypher query.